# Conditional redirection with Sharepoint Designer 2007

Tags: 2007, redirect

I have a button on a form that I use to commit the data and then redirect to another page.

What I am hoping to have is to be able to redirect to different pages based on the value of a type field.

Right now everything goes to one page using:

```
<input type="button" class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" value="Resubmit" name="btnResubmit" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={https://redirected_pageA.aspx}')}"/>
```

What I would like is something like:

```
If FieldType='A' then

    <input type="button" class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" value="Resubmit" name="btnResubmit" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={https://redirected_pageA.aspx}')}"/>

else if FieldType="B" then

    <input type="button" class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" value="Resubmit" name="btnResubmit" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={https://redirected_pageB.aspx}')}"/>

else if FieldType="C" then

    <input type="button" class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" value="Resubmit" name="btnResubmit" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={https://redirected_pageC.aspx}')}"/>

Endif
```

Can anyone help me to get this end logic?  I am using Sharepoint Designer 2007.

Thanks in advance

Comment: George, please share the button html code - this can be done by calling some JavaScript...

Comment: Sorry Arsalan... I had pasted it in but hadn't noticed that it didn't come across.  Here it is...<input type="button" class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" value="Resubmit" name="btnResubmit" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={http://page_a.aspx}')}"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

George,

Jim Bob Howard has wonderful article series on DataViewWebParts and here is what you are looking for:

[Extending the DVWP: Passing XSL Variables to Javascript](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Extending-the-DVWP-Passing-XSL-Variables-to-Javascript.aspx), in this article look into "Dynamic Querystring in a Redirect" section...

So you will write something like this in your click event:

```
if($FieldType == 'A') { ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;concat(__redirect={https://redirected_pageA.aspx}') } else if ($FieldType == 'B') { ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;concat(__redirect={https://redirected_pageB.aspx}') }
```

Or simply have a look at First Feedback on [this article](http://geekswithblogs.net/sevans/archive/2007/05/14/112496.aspx)

I hope this will work!